# I am making a calculator in android but i am getting error in adding two values

Tags: android

I have 2 edit text field where i am getting values from user than i have four buttons add multiply subtract and divide when user give the values and press one of the button the program will perform specific task which i have assign to it and it will give the result in text view but i am getting error in adding two values.
Here is my effort.

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView textView1;
Button button1,sub,mul,divi;
EditText editText1,editText2;
double a,b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub);
mul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mul);
divi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.divi);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a=Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
        b=Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.button1){
            textView1.setText(""+ a+b);
        }
        else{textView1.setText("not working ");}
        }

}
```

[image: its my application]

Comment: Could you show us your logcat window (which contains the exact error)?

Comment: its not giving me error i think its a logical error

Comment: sir i have 18 warnings nothing else

Comment: What is the expected result and the given result?

Comment: Shouldn't `textView1.setText(""+ a+b);` be `textView1.setText(""+ (a+b));` ?

Comment: the result i want is to add two values when user click on add button

Comment: let me check @ShashankKadne

Comment: "not working" is too generic. Please tell us whats the actual problem is and what is intended o/p ?

Comment: The problem is that i am not getting the main point why this is not showing the added values in textview .i have implements onclicklistener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited the code this will work 100%.

```
    package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView textView1;
Button button1,sub,mul,divi;
EditText editText1,editText2;
double a,b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sub);
mul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mul);
divi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.divi);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a=Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
        b=Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.button1){
            textView1.setText(""+(a+b));
        }
        else{textView1.setText("not working ");}
        }

}
```

Comment: let me check where is fault

Comment: Here is your fault if button1 is for addition.button1.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Thankyou is working fine thanks alot it means i have to do for all the buttons thanks alot for this knowledge

Comment: @AitazazKhan and same thing i was trying to bring in your knowledge. Please don't mind instead of copying pasting the code. just try to learn.........

Comment: sorry bro your and my answer is same but the wording is different although i have voted up your answer @Tarsem

Comment: and sorry @Tarsem your answer was a bit tricky any how i have also voted up your answer

Answer (score 4):

**First**

You are missing `Parenthesis`,

Here  `textView1.setText(""+ a+b);` `+ operator` is acting as concatenation

*So change your code to*

```
textView1.setText(""+ (a+b));
```

***PS.***
Second :

I think you are also forgetting to Register the `onClickListener` to `button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);`

So use this `button1.setOnClickListener(this)` in your `onCreate()`

Comment: actually i am adding the value than i want to show it in in the text view where hello world is written as i shown above in the snapshot

Comment: i have implemented onclicklistner i dont need to set again

Comment: For the OnClickListener to work you have to either add it programmatically as he said (button1.setOnClickListener(this)) or add it from XML with the android:onClick="onClick" attribute.

Comment: @AitazazKhan but you need to register  `onClickListener` i.e which `onClick()` should be called when button is clicked just think about it

Answer (score 3):

Try `textView1.setText(""+ (Double)(a+b));`

Answer (score 0):

Put  `android:inputType="number"`  in your Edittext of xml file.

Comment: And how would OP will be able to enter the `double value` ? i haven't downvoted but commented for your knowledge......